# Why does't rsync use delta-transfer for local files?

Tags: linux, rsync

I have a big iso image which is currently being downloaded by a torrent client with space-reservation turned on: that means, file size is not changing while some chunks in in (4 Mib) are constantly changing because of a download.

At 90% download I do the initial rsync to save time later:

```
$ rsync -Ph DVD.iso /media/another-hdd/
sending incremental file list

DVD.iso
       2.60G 100%   40.23MB/s    0:01:01 (xfer#1, to-check=0/1)

sent 2.60G  bytes  received 73 bytes  34.59M bytes/sec
total size is 2.60G   speedup is 1.00
```

Then, when the file's fully downloaded, I rsync again:

```
total size is 2.60G   speedup is 1.00
```

Speedup=1 says delta-transfer was not used, although 90% of the file has not changed, target dir is on another FS and copying takes several minutes. Why doen't it try to speedup the transfer?! How can I force `rsync` to use delta-transfer?

Comment: What you are doing does not make any sense.  The purpose of rsync is to speed up transferring files over the network, not locally.  In order to find the differences, it has to read both the source and destination.  In the time it takes to read the destination locally to find the differences, you may as well just do a normal copy.  Just download the file to the destination in the first place instead of copying it.

Comment: So it just does not use delta-xfer because, working locally, it's faster to copy than to calculate hashes? If yes — post the answer plz :)

Comment: Reading can be faster than writing to a local disk in certain circumstances. It can also reduce the wear on an SSD. This is certainly a valid question and the answer is quite valuable to me.

Comment: @psusi apart from HRJ's comment above, also consider the case when the target file has been reflinked (eg on btrfs or ocfs2). Minimizing writes during the sync can make an enormous difference to the overall space usage.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

According to the [manpage](https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rsync.html), psusi is right:

> **-W, --whole-file**:
>   The transfer may be faster if this option is used when the bandwidth between the source and destination machines is higher than the bandwidth to disk (especially when the "disk" is actually a networked filesystem).  This is the default when both the source and destination are  specified  as local paths, but only if no batch-writing option is in effect.

Comment: Oh, thank you! I miseed this line :) To turn delta-trasfer on, use `-no-W`

Comment: On my system `-no-W` doesn't work only the long option `-no-whole-file`.
 
My reason for needing this switch is when I'm setting up a backup and have large files (eg images) that don't have the same modification time. It is MUCH faster, speedup is 163.26, to sync these files using the delta-transfer on my local filesystem.

Comment: @JessetheWindWanderer, the long option is `--no-whole-file` (please, note the double `--` at the beginning).

Comment: Thanks Eddie C. I'd edit my comment if I could figure our how :-(

Comment: If the files are equal but with different mtime, another option is to use -c or --checksum, to make rsync calculate and compare the checksums and find out ther are equal. Then only the mtime is updated (provided -t o -a is given)  and the content is not touched.

Answer (score 19):

The straight-forward answer to this question is:

Use the `--no-W` flag to force delta compression, no matter local or remote.

**Update:** It looks like there is more to the story. The `delta compression` seems to be enabled only between receive and transmit process of rsync. When outputting the file to the file-system, `rsync` may still write out the whole file(s), even with delta compression on.

See "Wakan Tanka's" investigation [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/291156/why-rsync-does-not-do-delta-transfer/291189#291189).

**Update 2:** The `--inplace` option writes only the changed parts of the file. However note that it conflicts with `--sparse` and is not recommended, by the manual, when the destination file is being used.

Comment: `--no-W` always transfer whole file in my case. Please check http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/291156/why-rsync-does-not-do-delta-transfer

Comment: @WakanTanka That is interesting! I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 5):

By default, rsync first creates a new copy of the target file and then replaces it, for various safety reasons. You can override this by specifying `--inplace` along with `--no-whole-file`. This tells rsync to do an in-place-edit of the target file, accepting the various risks (typically minor for this situation) as documented in the man page.

Answer (score 2):

By default `rsync` creates a copy of the file at the destination and then atomically replaces the original with the new copy.  This is done for safety reasons.  What you're looking for is the `--inplace` option, which will cause `rsync` to modify only the portions of the destination file which have changed relative to the source.

For the O.P's use-case, I recommend turning off pre-allocation as well, so that a sparse copy can be synced, which will be much faster.  For downloads, don't worry about fragmentation unless you're using a very ancient filesystem like VFAT.  Media files in particular are not read at the maximum performance of the storage media, so defragmenting them is a wasted effort.

To copy your downloads directory sparsely to the destination volume, I recommend these flags and operations, in this order:

```
rsync --ignore-existing -vxaHAXS /source /destination
rsync --inplace -vxaHAX /source /destination
```

The first pass will copy new files sparsely to the destination
The second pass will update existing files in-place, copying only the changes

Since it's doing sparse and in-place delta copies, you can run this repeatedly without incurring much extra IO.  Even if you have 20 torrents running simultaneously it's won't amplify the writes at the destination, or thrash the source/dest volumes.

Comment: What do you mean by "sparsely" here, Wil ? It doesn't really reflect the actual meaning of the word, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Julius: it means exactly what it implies - copy the files with full support for sparse allocation, so for example your 40GB HDR movies will not take up any more space at the destination than they do at the source.  Same with VirtualBox disk images.  As stated the O.P. would need to disable pre-allocation for that to work.